# vscode - Is there a way to create an instance of `vscode.TextDocument`?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm listening for `onWillSaveTextDocument` and getting an instance of `vscode.TextDocument` which I use for file content and file path information.

It would be convenient to just create a new instance of this object, rather than recreating all of the information from a file path.

I'm hoping there is something like:

```
const document = new TextDocument(myFilePath);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could simply use [`vscode.workspace.openTextDocument`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#workspace.openTextDocument) method to create TextDocument instance.

An example would be:

```
    vscode.workspace.openTextDocument( {
        language: 'text'
    } )
    .then( doc => {
        // Do something useful with the document.
    });
```

If you'd like to see it used in context, feel free to see [this part of code](https://github.com/mlewand-org/vscode-test-set-content/blob/4282dd9903210798d768fe4738cb208fd07c5bf9/src/index.js#L17-L19).

Comment: I was afraid that this would actually open the file in the editor, but it didn't. It worked exactly the way I hoped. Thank you! This is perfect. :)

Comment: I'm trying to create a [custom binary editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors) for a file that has text data. On surface, the file is basically text, but it's saved as binary. I wanted to create a VSCode custom editor that uses VS `textDocument` underneath it. My custom editor responsibility would be read the binary, get the text, and give it to the *default text document model* from VS - even the view could be same.