# vscode - Is there a way to create an instance of `vscode.TextEditor`?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[vscode - Is there a way to create an instance of `vscode.TextDocument`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704792/vscode-is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-vscode-textdocument)

The question above except instead of textdocument I want for texteditor given the filepath.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

You can only *show* a `TextDocument`, using `vscode.window.showTextDocument(someTextDocument, ...)`, where `someTextDocument` refers to some `TextDocument` instance, previously opened.

Hope this helps