# How to get the language identifier from a file path

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode extension. The language identifier in the question refers to the string got through the [TextDocument.languageId](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument) property.

I know I can just use the property, but I must open this file first, which is something I want to avoid.

The method I am currently using is to parse the file extension, but considering that vscode can customize file associations, this is not a good method too.

Is there a more convenient and formal way to obtain the language identifier besides these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use workspace.openTextDocument (after importing {workspace} from `vscode` ) to create a TextDocument using your uri, and then extract the languageId from it.

The following code should do what you want

```js
await workspace.openTextDocument(uri).then(doc => {
    const language = doc.languageId;
    console.log(language);
  });
```

The documentation does make it seem like this opens a file (at least that's what I first assumed when I read it) but the replies to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42707683/22348094) thwarted those concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tested this function with procmon, it doesn't open an editor, but unfortunately it actually reads the file.